# How to take (still) picture with LifeCam HD 5000 under Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, camera

Have updated LifeCam application and it has disappeared. May be it is turned into Camera metro application -- it is impossible to check where recent application went in Windows 8.

So, is it possible to take still pictures with Camera application?

Comment: I have the same camera and I was able to take pictures. If you are having a hard time findng it I would just install the old version of the software. The built-in Windows 8 camera/picture application can also take pictures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is yes. I have the same web cam and I ended up with two metro apps after I upgraded, one called Camera and one called LifeCam. As soon as I start up the Camera app, it previews what the camera sees in full screen; I then click anywhere on the screen to snap a still photo.

The LifeCam app lets you organize photos, although I don't really use it.

Comment: By `LifeCam` you mean `LifeCam Dashboard` application? Or there is one named namely `LifeCam`?

Comment: @Dims - He is talking about `LifeCam Dashboard`.

Comment: Correct, it is the LifeCam Dashboard.